# Synonyms for "implement" regarding an idea and differences

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

Could you please tell me what verbs I can use instead of the verb *to implement* when talking about an idea? Could you also explain the differences between them?

Are the following sentences correct?

> A: I want to implement this idea.
>
> B: I want to realise this idea.
>
> C: I want to carry out this idea / carry this idea out.
>
> D: I want to put this idea into practice / effect.
>
> E: I want to actualise this idea.

Answer (score 1):

Words like *implement, realise* and *actualise* are fairly "technical, formal". In ordinary conversation native speakers are more likely to say...

> *I want [to put this idea into practice](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22to%20put%20this%20idea%20into%20practice%22)* (About 2,070 results in Google Books)

Comment: Thanks. That's helpful. But as for my example sentences, they are all correct, right? Good to know that "implement" sounds quite technical or formal.

Answer (score 0):

The verbs "execute", "achieve", "fulfill", "acomplish", "perform" or effectuate can be used with a similar meaning to "implement".

Comment: Can you even say "I want to acomplish/achieve that idea"?

Comment: Sorry, I realised that "even say" is ambiguous. It's not like I totally doubt it, so don't put the emphasis on "say" ... I just want to confirm if that sentence is really correct ...

Comment: @fill: If I wanted to use "accomplish" for your question, I would probably write it either as:

"I want to turn this idea into an acomplishment."

   or

"I want to accomplish putting this idea into effect."

(although that second sentence is a little clunky).